# How to start another activity after a splash screen in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hi everyone I'm studying now and developing a app in android studio. My problem is i can't proceed to my log in activity after splash screen. I already look in the net and stackoverflow and applied it, but still same error. I appreciate for the help and answer.

Here are some of my code

SplashScreen.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final Intent mainIntent =  new Intent(SplashScreen.this, Login.class);
            SplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            SplashScreen.this.finish();
        }
    },3000);

}
```

Login.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
  }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Login"/>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ex.app.MainActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

where did i go wrong ?

Comment: Show error logs

Comment: actually there's no error, just after splash screen it don't direct to login instead it direct to mainactivity. so i'd like it to direct to login activity.

Comment: Its because in your login activity you have given intent to main activity.This function will trigger when login activity is triggered so you cannot see the login actiivty

Comment: remove  this code from login.java Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

Comment: @natsuVsnaruto just comment the intent line or give the intent line inside a button click. then u can see the login page

Comment: Thank you very much for tha answer. I'll apply that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have written code to move to `MainActivity` on the method `onCreate` of `Login.java`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

*Comment this line or keep it on the click of SignIn button*

Comment: @natsuVsnaruto as you have login screen then must be you'll be having some code to check whether give Id-pwd (credentials) are valid or not. if they are valid then you should start your MainActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Your login activity just directs you to the MainActivity on create

Look at these lines

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is redirecting to MainActivity directly as in your LoginActivity onCreate you have written

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

without any condition. Make it conditional by putting your login check conditions and criteria

```
if (<logged_in_your_condition_Check>){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why you require below lines in Login.class

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

if you are using finish() in onCreate() then it will immediately called onDestroy() and that dosen't make any sense.

remove above given code from onCreate your code will work

Answer (score 0):

in manifest write:

```
<activity
android:name=".MySplashActivity"
android:noHistory="true"
 ..... >
    ....
</activity>
```

then in create() or somewhere different cal the method:

```
 private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT=2000;

 
private void nextScreen() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(()-> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MySplashaActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```